# TinyMCE <ol> <li> not working properly

Tags: php, content-management-system, tinymce

i'm using **CMSMS (CMS Made simple)** in my project. 
but the problem occur when we are using `<ol><li>` tags; when numbering goes 1 to 10 or above then it will creates problem for me. its displaying properly 1 to 9 but after 9 that will restarted from 0 instead of 10..
what can i do for resolve this..? is anybody having the solution for this..? 
Below image is what i m facing now..

[image]

**its creating problem for first 10th `<li>` only..after that it working nice for 20th,30th etc..**

Please help me out..

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't add a second OL unintentionally? go to HTML and delete the first `</ol>`

Comment: no dude...only one <ol></ol>..:(

Comment: If you paste the html on a page and run it, do you see all the numbers correctly? It's strange a list starting with zero, might be some wrong alignement that hides the first figure? It never occurred to me this error..

Comment: yes, its working good in simple page..but not in CMSMS..:(

Comment: from here it looks like the numbers are there but hidden, because the CSS is set incorrectly. try to adjust the margin and padding settings.
UPDATE: look into the DOM with Firebug or something similar, if they are there or not.